# Combining html5 progress bar with javascript and CGI script and C backend

Tags: javascript, c, html, cgi, progress

I'm pretty new to everything concerning webbased programming. I have the following progress bar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Progress Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(!Modernizr.meter){
                alert('Sorry your brower does not support HTML5 progress bar');
            } else {
                var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
                    max = progressbar.attr('max'),
                    time = (1000/max)*5,    
                    value = progressbar.val();

                var loading = function() {
                    value += 1;
                    addValue = progressbar.val(value);

                    $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

                    if (value == max) {
                        clearInterval(animate);                    
                    }
                };

                var animate = setInterval(function() {
                    loading();
                }, time);
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works pretty well based on a timer. I now want to fill that progress bar with the help of data from a c program. The Scenario is

1. the "value" must be updated with progress data from the c program i need to call.
2. if i understand right i need to call a CGI script which then opens up a pipe to my c program to catch the stdout of that c program.
3. that stdout data from my c program will then be redirected through the cgi back to the html5 document and update the progress bar.

Problem with that: Is that the right way to do it? Or am i understanding that wrong?

An alternative would be to open a websocket in html5 and adding a socket communcation thread to my c program and then they could both communicate. Is that possible with updating the progress bar in realtime in mind?